# Using Cocoa instead of the being deprecated Carbon framework

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, macos-carbon

The `Carbon framework` will soon be deprecated in the near future.

My first question is whether the deprecation is targeted towards a particular release i.e. whether it's incompatible with 64-bit machines?

Also, since it is known to be deprecated, we are working towards removing the `Carbon` dependencies and using `Cocoa framework` instead. While removing some, I came across the use of `EventRecord struct` defined in the `Events.h` file. What should be the `Cocoa` equivalent of the above struct i.e. I should be able to loop through the Event records while using cocoa too.

Comment: In reference to your 2nd paragraph:  Nobody can predict what Apple will do in the future, not even people inside Apple.  After all, Apple announced that they would make Carbon work in 64 bits, before they decided they wouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

Carbon does work with 64-bit machines, but it doesn’t work in a 64-bit mode, it works in 32-bit mode. You definitely want off it.

Cocoa has NSEvents (NSEvent.h), but a lot of what EventRecord appears to cover just isn’t relevant in Cocoa. Like, you don’t have to worry about “this portion of the window was uncovered” events—the system just calls “-drawRect:” on your NSView subclass.